# Not able to consume Web Service method when using asp.net forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-services, forms-authentication

One of my asp.net page using a Web Service Object to get the data from Database, its working fine locally as well as hosted server if `NOT using Forms Authentication`, when use the forms authentication method for the same page, getting the following run-time error,

```
Error :The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fLogon.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fChocolates.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

I'm using `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />` in web.config,

Please help me to get an answer for this problem.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456289/strange-error-object-moved-to-here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to exclude "chocolates.asmx" from the forms authentication?
example:

```
<location path="path_to_the_file_or_folder">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```